# Scratchy sound output on windows xp sp3

Tags: sound-card

My computer is Dell optiplex 380, OS is windows xp sp3 with lastest update. 
Driver details:

```
Title: Audio: Realtek ALC269 HD Audio Driver
Version    : A02
OEM name   : Realtek
OEM Version: 5874
```

The drivers are installed from driver disk and shouldn't have any problem.

My problem is, the left side of my headphone has strong noise, no matter I change the headphone, or change audio output port in front of the case or back of the case, the problem still exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to first try a new set of headphones, and a different output jack, to eliminate cabling and headphones as potential problems.

Here's the product page for the [Realtek ALC 269](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsview.aspx?langid=1&pfid=27&level=5&conn=4&prodid=166)

You might try the [High Definition Audio Codecs driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) direct from Realtek and see if that works any better.

Comment: Wiring is likely to be the issue. Try a different pair of headphones.